# Idiomatic Elixir - Function Parameter Style

Tags: function, parameters, elixir

*draw* and *hand* variables are lists.  I want to move the top card off the draw and add it to the hand.  This is the function:

```
def pick_up_card(draw, hand) do
  [new_card | new_draw ] = draw
  {hand ++ [new_card], new_draw}
end
```

I *could* rewrite it to a line shorter by including the [head | tail] part in the parameter list:

```
def pick_up_card([new_card | new_draw], hand) do
  {hand ++ [new_card], new_draw}
end
```

Would that be more idiomatic Elixir?  Would it be harming readability?  I would imagine the code would be easier to read later if the function definition had the name of the incoming list rather than a Head|Tail call.

Is it a matter of personal taste, or am I better saving that line of code and sticking the Head|Tail call in the function definition?

Comment: Do you need to add `new_card` to the end of `hand`? If not more efficient to do `{[new_card|hand], new_draw}`. You two alternative result in basically same code, just different error if the `draw` is not a list.

Comment: Yeah, for the purpose of this function, I'm taking the card off the _draw_ list and adding it to the _hand_ list.  (Whether it's added to the front or the end of the _hand_ list doesn't really matter, though.)  In real world terms, I'm picking a card up and adding it to my hand.

Comment: If you don't care where you add it to the `hand` list, then Robert's suggestion is better, since adding to the top of the list is O(1), while adding to the tail is O(n).

Comment: Thanks, Sasa.  That's a very good point about O(1).  I might rewrite more than just this function based on that point. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it's better to put it in the parameter list. You would probably like to write another clause

def pick_up_card([], _), do: raise "Nothing to pickup"

in the near future, don't you? :) Or care for other special cases - so it's better to put it in the header from the very beginning.

Comment: The check for an empty list happens in the step before the one I have in the example. If there's nothing to pick up from the draw stack, it's effectively game over and the program goes in a different direction.

Comment: So both options are effectively the same and you will likely see the second example as more frequent.

Comment: Thanks, Jose.  That makes the most sense, then.